# Why don't aircrafts spin their wheels before landing?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, aircraft

I had this thought when I was on the aircraft when it landed in the runway. It made lots of smoke and all sorts of vibrations, you know.

When I enquired about it, I came to know that the landing part was the toughest for an aircraft's tyres, and they were made to withstand it.

I wondered how much wear and tare would happen to the tyres, with an acceleration like that.

Why don't the aircrafts have ***powered wheels***, which would keep the wheels spinning *in sync* with the ground, before it lands?

I wonder why they still keep the wheels free. Won't this help increase the tyre's lifetime and make the landing less **bumpy**?

[image: landing plane]

Or, is there any(physics)thing  involved in the process, for example, the *sidewise **turning effect** on the aircraft due to spinning of wheels*,etc ?

Comment: See [Why are aircraft tires not pre-spun prior to landing to preserve them?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3702/) on the Aviation Stack Exchange. This is more of an engineering question than a physics question.

Comment: Right. I got it.